# What to do after starting a rails server on localhost:3000?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, testing

I am new to rails. I have followed instructions and setup a rails server. I have an application on my computer. I have started localhost:3000 and I don't know what to do next step.

I did try a few other solutions, but nothing explains the next step.

Thank you

Comment: What do you want to do as next step ?

Answer (score 1):

Due to the vague question and i am not allowed to comment you to ask question, thanks to @StackoverflowTeam.

Some suggestion when i learn Ruby on Rails, since your application is up,

1. You should learn to create a `Model`(a table in the DB).
2. Create a `Controller` to handle `HTTP requests`
3. Learn about the `app/config/routes.rb` to handle `customise url` map to `controller_name:action_name`.

Okey, good for you to start.
I have found this free videos interesting, hope you like it [codeschool ruby on rails](https://www.codeschool.com/courses/rails-for-zombies-redux)